# deployJava js forces to update jre 1.6 to 1.7+

Tags: java, java-web-start, deployjava

I have a java web start application which runs from a web page. I use deployJava.js to detect java installation on user's system. Minimum java version required is 1.6. However even if user has only 1.6 installed it still forces user to update it to 1.7 or 1.8(just runs autoupdate automatically and you can do nothing to it). 
How can I stop autoupdate and run app using already installed version of java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I stop autoupdate..

AFAIK you can't.  Not that you should.  Earlier versions of the JRE might have (known, published, and eminently exploitable) security bugs.

Comment: yeah. I found that in deployJava.js it checks if 1.7+ is not installed it forces to install it.